# The variable taken from another previous view controller but I could not reach that value(nil error)?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uiimageview

I know that this is an async. request but I have already taken my `posterPathOfMov` from the previous `viewcontroller`. I could not
really understand where is the problem.

```
import UIKit

class DetailMovieController: UIViewController {
    //Taken from previous VC but despite posterPathOfMov is not nil I could not request a web service the data
    var movieTitle : String!
    var descriptionMovie : String!
    var posterPathOfMov : String!

    let imageOfMovie : UIImageView = {
        let img = UIImageView()
        img.backgroundColor = .red
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = false
        return img
    }()

    let titleOfMovie : UILabel = {
        let tit = UILabel()
        tit.backgroundColor = .blue
        tit.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tit
    }()

    let descOfMovie : UILabel = {
        let desc = UILabel()
        desc.backgroundColor = .yellow
        desc.numberOfLines = 20
        desc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return desc
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Constraints for the views
        setUp()
        //Assignments
        descOfMovie.text = descriptionMovie
        titleOfMovie.text = movieTitle
        print(self.posterPathOfMov)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780\(self.posterPathOfMov)")!,completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in
            guard let imageData = data else {return}
            guard (err == nil) else {print(err!); return}
            print("hello2")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.imageOfMovie.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
            }
        });task.resume()
    }
```

Console Log is as  follows:

> /9E2y5Q7WlCVNEhP5GiVTjhEhx1o.jpg
>   fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: which line is crashing ? Try doing this in viewWillAppear as DidLoad is only called once not every time.Also where are you assigning value to that variable?

Comment: @TusharSharma 
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780\(self.posterPathOfMov)")!,completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in
this line is crashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the URL isn't valid. When you string-interpolate an implicitly unwrapped optional, it includes `Optional(...)` in the string. Your URL is:

```
https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780Optional("/9E2y5Q7WlCVNEhP5GiVTjhEhx1o.jpg")
```

That's not a valid URL, and so your `!` crashes.

Wrap this code in `if let posterPathOfMov = posterPathOfMov` to get rid of the Optional (or add a `??` to resolve it). This issue would be more obvious if you switched to using regular `?` optionals rather than `!`.

Answer (score 0):

First off, never force unwrap an optional unless you're positive that it's not nil:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780\(self.posterPathOfMov)")!
```

Despite what you assume about the string in self.posterPathOfMov, this code is not producing a valid URL.

The reason the URL is invalid is you have posterPathOfMov declared as String!

This is an optional, so URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780(posterPathOfMov)") produces nil.

You can fix this with:

```
if let path = posterPathOfMov {
    let url = URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780\(path)")
}
```

Here's cleaner working Swift code:

```
if let path = self.posterPathOfMov,
    let url = URL(string:"https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780\(path)") {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in
        guard let imageData = data else {return}
        guard (err == nil) else {print(err!); return}
        print("hello2")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.imageOfMovie.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```